# Difficulty understanding nested loops with addition, range and print function

Tags: python, loops, nested, range, addition

When I put this python code with input 12, the answer is 0, 6, 18. I dont know how to calculate that and I keep visualizing it as code snippet 2, with the answers 0,0,1,3,6,6,8,12.

How does this loop work?

```
stop=int(input())
result=0
for a in range(5): 
  for b in range(4): 
    result += a * b
  print(result)
  if result > stop: 
    break
```

What I calculate

```
stop=int(input())
result=0
for a in range(5): 
  for b in range(4): 
    result += a * b
    print(result)
  if result > stop: 
    break
```

[picture of my calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLg2c.png)

Comment: What is unclear to you about this? I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: So when I do this manually by hand, I run through each possibility so when a=0, etc., and I get 0,0,1,3,6,6,8,12. I don't know how the 0, 6 and 18 are calculated because I don't know how to calculate the above code (first image on top) I also included a picture of what Im trying to calculate but I don't get 0, 6, and 18.

Comment: don't print out values until the `b` loop is completed, that's it

Comment: There's no need to do input. Just specify the integer in the question. That skips steps and makes it easier to reproduce. (Unless the input is not what you think it is, in which case that's the problem.) It looks like the output of 0, 6, 18 is correct to me. Do you want help with something python related or basic math? 0+0+0+0 is 0, so that checks out. 0+1+2+3 is 6 so that checks out. 0+2+4+6=12 and 12+6 is 18 so that checks out. And 18 > 12 so it ends. That checks out.

Comment: Why don't you do the same calculations on paper for the first code, and you will see what it does?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Its a bit embarrasing for me but I don't know how to do the first code. With the print being indented or not I don't know what the difference is. Would the result being printed also be from result += a * b or since its outside will it just return the value of return without the equation result += a * b

Comment: You can use [this website](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=stop%3D12%0Aresult%3D0%0Afor%20a%20in%20range%285%29%3A%20%0A%20%20for%20b%20in%20range%284%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%2B%3D%20a%20*%20b%0A%20%20print%28result%29%0A%20%20if%20result%20%3E%20stop%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20break&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) to visualize the execution. I think this should clear this up for you. It will be difficult to explain it in words otherwise.

Comment: ah ... well there's a for loop. I skipped the multiplication and just printed the terms. Hey do you have a debugger? for b in [0, 1, 2, 3] result += 0 * b ... that's 0 + 0 + 0 + 0

Comment: Thank you! @mkrieger1 thats a great website I appreciate everyones help

Comment: @KennyOstrom I do not unless Pycharm counts? (I just started learning a month ago so Im very new and my questions may sound stupid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll walk you through your `for a in range(5)` loop.

First, a = 0, result = 0.

- This loops 4 times and result remains at 0 because 0 * b = 0
- 0 is printed

Next, a = 1, result = 0.

- Result += 1x0 + 1x1 + 1x2 + 1x3
- So result = 0 + 6
- 6 is printed

Finally, a = 2, result = 6.

- Result += 2x0 + 2x1 + 2x2 + 2x3
- So result = 6 + 12 = 18
- 18 is printed
- `if result > stop` evaluates to true so the loop is broken.